# How to look up YouTube Live Chat Ban ID to delete it

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

The YouTube Live Streaming API has the ability to ban and un-ban a user from chat and provides the following method specifically to perform the un-banning:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatBans/delete

The API requires you to pass the id parameter that identifies the chat ban to remove and states that the value uniquely identifies both the ban and the chat. However, there does not appear any way to look up the chat bans for a channel, other than when you get the ID back initially when the ban occurs.

So is there no way to un-ban a user via the API long after the ban has occurred and you no longer have the ban ID?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, LiveChatBanId is a base64-encoded string containing

- banned user *channel id*
- *owner channel id*
- some random bytes?

Here is some python code that will generate it for you

```py
import base64
banned_user_id = 'banned user id'
owner_channel_id = 'channel owner id'

decoded = f"\x08\x01\x12\x18{banned_user_id}\x1a8\n\r\n\x0b7cHT2DHCA7s*'\n\x18{owner_channel_id}\x12\x0b7cHT2DHCA7s".encode('utf-8')
encoded = base64.b64encode(decoded)
print(encoded)
```

Fill in **banned_user_id** and **owner_channel_id**

You may need to invoke the "LiveChatBans: delete" method twice, that's how Google works